# Event bubling JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, d3.js, dom-events

I have two elements which are one on top of another inside a parent g container.
polygon [polygon-img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMkCb.png) and textarea [textarea-img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8ceX.png), parent g container has a d3.js drag handler attached to it with code below

```
useEffect(() => {
  const zoneNode = zoneRef.current;
  let dragBehavior;
  if (isEditing && !isPlacingText && !zone.isEditingText) {
    dragBehavior = d3.drag().on("drag", zoneDrag).on("end", zoneDragEnd);
  } else {
    dragBehavior = d3.drag().on("drag", null).on("end", null);
  }
  d3.select(zoneNode).datum(position).call(dragBehavior);
}, [isEditing, isPlacingText, zone]);
```

when i click on textarea dom node the drag event is fired as well as when i click on polygon, is there any way to restrict this behaviour and make it fire only when i click on polygon?

Comment: You can look at the drag event's `target` and `currentTarget` and cancel it accordingly.

Comment: @AKX the problem is that if you try to start dragging on the place where these two nodes overlap textarea comes on top and because of that drag event isn't fired if you cancel it via target, is there any workaround to make drag event to go through textarea like it isnt there at all?

Comment: You could try the `pointer-events: none` CSS style on the textarea if you want it to pass clicks through.

Comment: @AKX ty man this worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make my comment an answer:

You can use the [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) CSS property to effectively make the `<textarea>` pass through for mouse events:

```
pointer-events: none
```